# Sharepoint 2010 owssvr.dll Display versioned list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

There's a parameter that I've added in the past to owssvr.dll calls with Display that returns each row of the version history for each row in the list.

A small backup failure has lost the queries that did it for me. Can someone help me reconstruct them?

Answer (score 0):

&IncludeVersions=TRUE appears to do the trick - I'll have to add the modified by and when fields to a view though

Comment: Thanks for useful information.
Do you know the way to display Modified by and modified date fields?